# Cant Select data from MySQL database with Volley library in Android

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-volley

I want to select two string data from MySQL database using an `id` from that table and then I want to show them in two `EditText`. I really don't know why it's not working.

My table has 5 columns : `user_id, resumeSubject, resumeText, email, fullname`. And in my table I have a particular row that I want it's `resumeSubject` and `resumeText` fields.

**It's my PHP file:**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("HOST", "UserName", "Password", "Database Name");

$user_id = $_POST["user_id"];
$email = $_POST["email"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM resumeUserList WHERE user_id = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "i", $user_id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $user_id, $resumeSubject, $resumeText, $email, $fullname);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;  

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"] = true;        
    $response["resumeSubject"] = $resumeSubject;
    $response["resumeText"] = $resumeText;
}

echo json_encode($response); ?>
```

**And It's my Request Class:**

```
public class Request extends StringRequest {
    private static final String REQUEST_URL = "URL";

    private Map<String, String> params;

    public Request(int user_id, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Method.POST, REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("user_id", user_id +"");
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

And It's my `ReceiveActivity`:

```
public class Receive extends Activity {

    private static int user_id;
    private static String fullname, email;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_receive);

        final EditText resumeSubjectText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subjectId);
        final EditText resumeTextText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.massageId);

        Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                    if (success) {
                        String resumeSubject = jsonResponse.getString("resumeSubject");
                        String resumeText = jsonResponse.getString("resumeText");

                        resumeSubjectText.setText(resumeSubject);
                        resumeTextText.setText(resumeText);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        Request request = new Request(user_id, responseListener);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(CommonUserList_User.this);
        queue.add(request);  }
}
```

What is my mistake here?

Comment: So, what's the output you're getting?

Comment: So did you debug your code? Are you getting the data from your server in the Android side? Or your php code is sending no data? Please be very specific with your problem.

Comment: Where is loginRequest declared? You declared Request but added loginRequest to queue. Shouldnt it be `Request loginRequest = new Request(...` I am wondering that you could compile it like this.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question accordingly to the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) directives.

Comment: @steven Sorry loginRequest is Request, I forgot to chage it.

Comment: @ReazMurshed I think my php file is not working well and dosn't change success to true.

Comment: @IvanPronin Nothing, i even don't get an error from catsh statement.

Comment: Try to make your php file working first before you went to java. Test it in browser and temporarily change fetching of post vars to $_GET vars to make browser debigging easier. Do some debugging outputs to find out whats going wrong. If you got it go back to java. It makes no sense to continue app development if you are not sure that your php backend is stable.

Comment: And enable php error reporting while debugging may help you.